# Can't get the EditorFor value in jquery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an `<td>@Html.EditorFor(m => m.User.Username)</td>` in RegisterView. Here is the HTML on fireBUg:

```
  <td>
<input id="User_Username" class="text-box single-line" type="text" value="" name="User.Username" data-val-required="The Username field is required." data-val="true">
</td>
```

I write a litte jquery code to check username whether or not the username exits. Here is my code:

```
function CheckUserNameExits() {
$("#User_Username").on("blur", function () {
    $("#User_Username").addClass("thinking");
    var username = $("#User_Username").val();
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Account/CheckUsername",
        data: { userName: username },
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
        error: function () {
            return;
        },
        success: function (data) {
            if (data) {
                $("#User_Username").addClass("approved");
            }
            else {
                $("#User_Username").addClass("denied");
                $(".field-validation-error").html("The username already exits.");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

}

But when i fill the textbox and leave it. The POST value always null. I'm sure my script works fine, it always return `true` because of the post value is null. My controller method:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CheckUsername(string userName)
    {
        var user = IUserRepo.GetUserByUrName(userName);
        if (user!= null)
            return Json(false);
        return Json(true);
    }
```

In debug the `userName` parameter always null. I try to change `$("#User_Username")` by `$(".text-box")` but the POST value also null. Any sugesstion for me?

Comment: What browser are you debugging in? Is the post being sent to the server properly? What happens when you debug through the code

Comment: What do you get if you place `alert(username);` in your javascript function right below `var username = $("#User_Username").val();` I'm suspecting there is more than one ID=User_Username on your page because [THIS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/dknRf/) works fine with your code as-is.

Comment: It works fine, my mistake. Closed.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
function CheckUserNameExits() {
$("#User_Username").on("blur", function () {
    $("#User_Username").addClass("thinking");
    var username = $("#User_Username").val();
    $.ajax({
        contentType: "application/json, charset=utf-8",
        url: "/Account/CheckUsername",
        data: '{ "userName":"' + username + '"}',
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
        error: function () {
            return;
        },
        success: function (data) {
            if (data) {
                $("#User_Username").addClass("approved");
            }
            else {
                $("#User_Username").addClass("denied");
                $(".field-validation-error").html("The username already exits.");
                }
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give `id` to your `EditFor` and try

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.User.Username,new{id="EDUserName"})

function CheckUserNameExits() {
$("#EDUserName").on("blur", function () {
    $("#EDUserName").addClass("thinking");
    var username = $("#EDUserName").val();
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Account/CheckUsername",
        data: { userName: username },
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
        error: function () {
            return;
        },
        success: function (data) {
            if (data) {
                $("#EDUserName").addClass("approved");
            }
            else {
                $("#EDUserName").addClass("denied");
                $(".field-validation-error").html("The username already exits.");
            }
        }
    });
});
}
```